# Is there a legitimate way to ask how good / bad Hired! is without being subjective?

Tags: discussion

I just saw incendiary reviews of Hired! at http://blog.openviewpartners.com/hired-com-review/ , and suspect that there others, but would love to see some SE types give the good, the bad, and the ugly of seeking employment via Hired! The obvious problem is that the obvious ways I see of asking would be begging to be closed as subjective.

The obvious response I see is an LMGTFY link, but is there any way I can post a question on the non-meta site to identify how good, bad, or ugly Hired! is?

Comment: You are asking for opinions. By the rules, that is off-topic.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Just post that as an answer because it's pretty much true. I don't see how this would ever make a good question.

Answer (score 6):

You are asking for opinions (about Hired!). By the rules of this community, that is off-topic by definition.